# Why does SetCellEditor cause error when reapplied after self.m_grid_3.ClearGrid()

Tags: python, wxpython

The following code populates a grid each time the combobox is used to select a new value.
The first time the code runs it works fine and creates a populated grid with a drop down in each cell in col 4.  However when I select a second new value and the function executes the self.m_grid_3.ClearGrid() and repopulates I get the following error.

```
  self.m_grid3.SetCellEditor(row, col, self.choice_editor)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\grid.py", line 2000, in SetCellEditor
  return _grid.Grid_SetCellEditor(*args, **kwargs)
  TypeError: in method 'Grid_SetCellEditor', expected argument 4 of type 'wxGridCellEditor *'
```

Selecting a dropdown in col4 then crashes python.

Any ideas how I can fix this.

Here is the code in question.

```
class Inspection(BulkUpdate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        BulkUpdate.__init__(self, parent)
        list = EmployeeList()
        list_climbers = list.get_climbers()
        for name in list_climbers:
            self.edit_kit_comboBox.Append(str(name.employee))
        choices = ["Yes", "No", "Not Checked"]
        self.choice_editor = wx.grid.GridCellChoiceEditor(choices, True)


    def on_engineer_select( self, event ):
        self.m_grid3.ClearGrid()
        person = self.edit_kit_comboBox.GetValue()
        list = KitList()
        equipment = list.list_of_equipment(person, 1)
        rows = len(equipment)

        for row in range(0, rows):
            for col in range(0, 5):
                print "row = %s col = %s" % (row, col)
                if col == 4:
                    self.m_grid3.SetCellValue(row, col+2, str(equipment[row][col]))
                    self.m_grid3.SetCellValue(row, col, "Pass")
                    self.m_grid3.SetCellEditor(row, col, self.choice_editor)
                else:
                    self.m_grid3.SetCellValue(row, col, str(equipment[row][col]))
```

The code stops on the second loop while populating the grid the second time.
I have been trying to work this out for days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to `__init__`:

```
self.choice_editor.IncRef()
```

My guess is that the C++ portion of the editor object is being deleted when you call `ClearGrid`. Giving it that extra reference tells the Grid that you want to hold on to it.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the answer of adding

```
self.choice_editor.IncRef()
```

I moved the choices list definition into the function along with

```
self.choice_editor.IncRef()
```

So now it looks like this

```
def on_engineer_select( self, event ):
    self.m_grid3.ClearGrid()
    choices = ["Pass", "Fail", "Not Checked"]
    self.choice_editor = wx.grid.GridCellChoiceEditor(choices, False)
    person = self.edit_kit_comboBox.GetValue()
    list = KitList()
    equipment = list.list_of_equipment(person, 1)
    print "Length of equipment = %s" % len(equipment)
    rows = len(equipment)
    for row in range(0, rows):
        for col in range(0, 5):
            print "row = %s col = %s" % (row, col)
            if col == 4:
                self.choice_editor.IncRef()
                self.m_grid3.SetCellValue(row, col+2, str(equipment[row][col]))
                self.m_grid3.SetCellValue(row, col+1, str(date.today()))
                self.m_grid3.SetCellEditor(row, col, self.choice_editor)
                self.m_grid3.SetCellValue(row, col, "Pass")

            else:
                self.m_grid3.SetCellValue(row, col, str(equipment[row][col]))
```

Now the code works as desired.